# Access basic profile when user login in his/her iOS app

Tags: ios, objective-c, facebook, facebook-login

I have done with the Facebook graph api for facebook authentication or to get the user Facebook detail but with it I also want to implement one more thing in which .. Suppose user is already login on Facebook via Facebook iOS app in this case when I open my app or click on login button then it shows me alert which says that "*App would like to access your basic profile info*" like Friend Smasher app so that user will be able to get his basic profile by clicking Ok button but if user is not login on his Facebook iOS app then it may ask for username and password or login page.

If anyone know how to access the basic user profile in an app if user is already login in Facebook iOS app then please help me out.

Answer (score 0):

Given that you already have a user connected, this is how you can get his information.

```
FBRequest *userRequest = [FBRequest requestForGraphPath:@"/me/?fields=gender,interested_in,relationship_status,email,first_name,last_name,location,id,birthday"];

[userRequest startWithCompletionHandler:^(FBRequestConnection *connection, id result, NSError *error) {
    if (!error) {
         //For instance:
         NSLog([result first_name]);
         NSLog([result last_name]);
         NSLog([result birthday]);
         NSLog([result first_name]);
         NSLog([[result objectForKey:(@"location")] objectForKey:(@"name")]);
    } else {
         NSLog(@"User not found");
    }
];
```